# excel: how to count and +1

Tags: excel, addition

How can I do the yellow part?
even there are same text, I just want to count 1

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to post what you trued and divide the question into sections, its hard to understand the question and therefore hard to help you

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment, the question has been changed!

Comment: like B3:B14, there is only A, so just count 1 in the top cell of yellow; then C3:C14, there are B and C, even there are repeat, I wanna count the different word, so there is 2 in the top cell of yellow and so on.

I just want to count how many different word are appeared in the table and show it in the yellow part.

Comment: "How to count unique values in a range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you are looking for is called Count unique item in a list. Try below formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B14<>"")/COUNTIF(B3:B14,B3:B14&""))
```

If you have `Office365` then you can simplify it by using [UNIQUE()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-unique-function#:%7E:text=The%20Excel%20UNIQUE%20function%20returns,%2C%20dates%2C%20times%2C%20etc.&text=array%20%2D%20Range%20or%20array%20from%20which%20to%20extract%20unique%20values.) function like below

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(B3:B14))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended way**: Write `=SUM(1/COUNTIF(B2:B14,B2:B14))` in empty cell, press ctrl+shift+enter and extend to all you columns.

[How it works](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-unique-values.html)

Manual way: in excel select Data tab ->  Advanced ->  Click Copy to another location -> fill the source and dest -> **Select the Unique records only check box** -> ok.

that will copy just the unique values of your column then use =ROWS() and count the number of lines.

Comment: from Row B to Row E, there are 4 rows, if I have 100 rows, do I have to do 100 times for your steps?

Comment: Please take a look now